# how to deal with this ArraystoreException element type mismatch?

Tags: java, arraystoreexception

I have a problem with this code:

```
package com.josuecode.tournament;
import java.util.*;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList <Chessplayers> registers = new ArrayList <Chessplayers> ();

        Lists_methods.registrartion(registers,(short) 1);
        Chessplayers[][] round1 = new Chessplayers [2][(int) Math.ceil(registers.size() / 2)];
        round1 = registers.toArray(round1);

        for (int i = 0; i < round1.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(round1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I got this exception in the line 11

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, [Lcom.josuecode.tournament.Chessplayers;"

and I don't know why if both (the ArrayList and the Array) are of the same type.

in the ArrayList are stored Chessplayers class objects and I want to convert that List into java Array.

Comment: So you were expecting, maybe, that `toArray()` would convert an ArrayList of a given object type into a two-dimensional array of that object type? I don't think it's going to do that, how would it know which elements to put where? Also, in future, post the actual error message you get and mark the line with the corresponding line number, otherwise some people won't even read the whole post (like me on other days).

Comment: You're right. Thanks